# Android : Print imageview image

Tags: android, printing

I'm new to android, i'm doing my current app with print imageview image by using android default print settings. I'm using below code to print image. but while i'm running on emulator, i got output with save options not print option, and also running on device its not working.Can any one please suggest some ideas to do this.

```
PrintHelper photoPrinter = new PrintHelper(MainActivity.this);
    photoPrinter.setScaleMode(PrintHelper.SCALE_MODE_FILL);
    photoPrinter.printBitmap("test.jpg", imgbitmap );
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find out why this was not working on a device? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can print via intent also if any printing app is available.For this purpose u can get drawing cache of imageview and pass the uri using intent.piece of code for that as follows.

```
 Intent printIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            printIntent.setType("image/*");
            printIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE,
                    "some cool title for your document");
            Bitmap imageToSave = drawFragment.getDrawView().getWholeView();

            String imgSaved = FileUtil.saveImageInGallery(
                    getApplicationContext(), imageToSave);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(imgSaved);

            printIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

            startActivity(printIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PrintHelper printHelper = new PrintHelper(context);
printHelper.setScaleMode(PrintHelper.SCALE_MODE_FILL);
printHelper.printBitmap(printJobName, bitmap);
```